# How to add Google Auth to work along side AAD in Blazor server app?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, microsoft-identity-platform

I have a blazor server app that uses AAD for user authentication. Now I want to add Google auth to it, so that user can login either account. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) seems suggest that it should be as straightforward as to call the `AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(options => ...)`.

So here's my (simplified) implementation:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddGoogle(options =>
                {
                    options.ClientId = Configuration["GoogleAuthentication:ClientId"];
                    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["GoogleAuthentication:ClientSecret"];
                })
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
                {
                    Configuration.Bind(Microsoft.Identity.Web.Constants.AzureAd, options);
                })
```

Only the `AddGoogle` part is newly added. The existing AAD code has been working fine.

But I don't know what's the right next step to expose the Google login in UI. (For AAD, it's as simple as adding a log in link to "MicrosoftIdentity/Account/Login". )

Answer (score 0):

As the document description, you should choose "individual Accounts" authentication type. But not "Microsoft Identity platform"

[image]
[image] 
After create this template, then just add code before `var app = builder.Build();`
I take facebook auth as example because i use facebook:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
    {
        facebookOptions.AppId = "5919468125828xxxx";   //your AppID
        facebookOptions.AppSecret = "94da15ef56a859365e26be2a8550xxx"; //You App secrect
    });

var app = builder.Build();
```

You also need to add "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook" to make it work. (For google it is "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google")

Run the App, clicke "log in" at right top.
You will see login with facebook button and all works.
[image]

You can also reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wasn't clear in the question but using the asp.net core identity page seems requring you to use a data store, which is something we don't want. Only thing we need is the user's email (and probably photo from profile). We can customize the pages, such as the login and the externallogin page, but it is a rabbit hole I don't want to go in... I was hoping there's some package that maes things as easy as the AAD integration, but I guess that's not going to happen.. any suggestion on that?

Comment: @DaPanda Haven't seen such package before, this video may help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6nQf76HF20A